# how to write code if more then two getPoolElements in java code?

Tags: java

I have 10 field elements. I am storing each elements in different variables for calling. Except the variable name of getPoolElementId other code of lines are same... how to simplify my code.

This is the code...
here PoolElements can vary upto 10...

java.util.List elements = presSec.getPoolElements("area1");

```
if (elements!=null && !elements.isEmpty()) {
neo.xredsys.presentation.PoolElement poolElement =
            (neo.xredsys.presentation.PoolElement) elements.get(0);
    neo.xredsys.presentation.PresentationArticle article =
            poolElement.getArticle(publication.getId());
}

List<Integer> articleIdsArea1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (Iterator i = elements.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
    neo.xredsys.presentation.PoolElement pe = (neo.xredsys.presentation.PoolElement) i.next();
    tmpArticle = pe.getArticle(publication.getId());
    if (((List) pageContext.getAttribute("tps")).contains(tmpArticle.getArticleTypeName()))
        articleIdsArea1.add(tmpArticle.getArticleId());
}   
pageContext.setAttribute("areaId1", areaId1);
```

Comment: Show your code and we will have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Try using an array instead of ten different variables